# iPhone - How to design so that a UITableView can show big number of items?

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, core-data

I have a big number of items in CoreData db. A item is actually a news entity, which has tile, summary, content, etc.

I also have a single UITableView. What I am doing is that I read items from the CoreData db (not just read once for all, but eventually maybe all) and display them in the UITableView.

Suppose that `the number of items is very very big` and it is impossible read all items into the memory, so I need a buffering thing to display them all in the UITableView.

I know that `NSFetchedResultController` is the candidate to use as it loads data as need.

However, I think it just read more and more and never dump things, right?

**Then, in my case, how can I dynamically load/unload items from both ends?**

To be more precise, if I scroll the UITableView down, then I should load more items in that direction and remove items from memory in the opposite direction.

Is there a convenient way or automatic way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, use the NSFetchRequest's setBatchSize: method. This will allow the NSFetchedResultsController instance to keep only the number of the batchSize into memory. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html)'s the documentation for NSFetchRequest.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me how it works? So I get a `NSFetchedResultsController instance with batch size of 50. So at beginning, it contains real items 0 - 49. then if I scroll down the UITableView, at a certain point, it will load 50 - 99 and dump 0 - 49?

Comment: Yes, however I would recommend a higher number. Somewhere around 1000-2000. Keep in mind that the fetch is not dynamic. It won't be fetching as you are scrolling. It will just be faulting batches as you are scrolling.

Comment: Then what should I to fullfil those faults?

Comment: Nothing. Just like other faults in core data, you don't usually handle those faults. Specifically, in this case,  NSFetchedResultsController will handle those batch faults, when they are required to be presented in the interface.